# How to make Vim as MANPAGER hide line numbers by default?

Tags: vim

I use Vim as Manpager as follows:

```
export MANPAGER='vim -M +MANPAGER -'
```

Works pretty well but everytime I execute `man programname` it shows
line numbers. How can I hide the line numbers by default when using
vim as man pager? Currently I'm doing it manually everytime.

Note: I don't wanna hide the line numbers elsewhere, only when reading
man pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke `vim` with `set nonumber` to hide line numbers.

```
export MANPAGER='vim -M +MANPAGER "+set nonumber" -'
```